# Can an AWS Glue Job Script handle multiple streaming sources in the same job?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, aws-glue

In the process of trying to minimize the costs related to AWS Glue, I am attempting to join some of the Streaming Jobs (which currently run as separate jobs) into one. These jobs are very similar in nature:

1. they batch events from a kafka topic
2. apply some form of transformation
3. store the resulting dataframe in a Apache Hudi table

However, the script only seems to accept one streaming source (i.e. kafka topic) per script.

After a typical setup, I have the below:

```
glue_context.forEachBatch(
        frame=raw_data_frame_one,
        batch_function=batch_function_one,
        options={
            "windowSize": args["MICRO_BATCH_WINDOW_SIZE"],
            "checkpointLocation": args["TempDir"] + "/" + job_name_one + "/checkpoint/",
        },
    )


glue_context.forEachBatch(
        frame=raw_data_frame_two,
        batch_function=batch_function_two,
        options={
            "windowSize": args["MICRO_BATCH_WINDOW_SIZE"],
            "checkpointLocation": args["TempDir"] + "/" + job_name_two + "/checkpoint/",
        },
    )
```

I expect both raw data frames to be streamed, but in this case only `raw_data_frame_one` and `batch_function_one` are being used.

Also tried submitting these workloads in different threads (with `spark.scheduler.mode` as `FAIR`) to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spark Structured Streaming native integration with kafka and forEachBatch method to deal with several streams [official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

> Glue streaming is built based on Spark streaming which is micro-batch oriented and inherits all features of Spark Streaming.
> [ref](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/aaaabcab-5e1e-4bff-b604-781a804763e1/en-US/lab4)

So you can refer to differences between Spark Streaming and Spark Structured Streaming [here](https://blog.knoldus.com/spark-streaming-vs-structured-streaming/)

Whenever you try adding more streaming sources to Glue streaming you'll get

> Glue Studio currently only supports a single streaming source per job.

PS:

Btw [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/aws-glue-now-supports-serverless-streaming-etl/) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-serverless-streaming-etl-with-aws-glue/) (and also in other places across Glue documentation)  Glue streaming is announced as running on top of Spark Structured streaming, but anyways for now (Glue 4 version) it still supports only one streaming source